# Can't save form in Model Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save a form in my Model, but it isn't working as expected. 
When I am filling in the fields for the first time and press the button 'submit' the page is just reloading. When I try the second time, I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table user_profile_product has no column named product_user_id
```

My code:

Views.py

```
def post_product(request):
    form = ProductForm()
    template_name = 'user_profile/add_product.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['product_name']
            description = form.cleaned_data['product_description']
            price = form.cleaned_data['product_price']
            user = request.user
            product = Product(product_name=name, product_description=description, product_price=price, product_user=user)
            product.save()
            return render(request, 'home_page/home.html', {'product': product})
        else:
            form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=150 )
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    product_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
         super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    product_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=True)
    product_description = forms.CharField(max_length=300, required=True)
    product_price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_name', 'product_description', 'product_price')
```

Migration file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('product_name', models.CharField(max_length=150)),
                ('product_description', models.CharField(max_length=300)),
                ('product_price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)),
                ('product_user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Update:

When I remove my foreign key product_user I can save the form in my model, but when I try to save it with the foreign key and specify request.user it is not working. Am I doing something wrong in my model?

Comment: Do you run ```manage.py migrate```?

Comment: Yes, I did ```py manage.py makemigrations``` when I first created the model and after migrated it.

Comment: And ```py manage.py migrate```? Can you show migration files?

Comment: Yes, I also did ```py manage.py migrate```.

Comment: Hmm, can use show full stack of error
```django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: user_profile_product.product_user_id```

What lines?

Comment: You need to clean database (delete all tables)

Comment: And try to change string:

```
product = Product(name, description, price, user)
```

to 

```
product = Product(name=name, description=description, price=price, user=user)
```

Comment: I did the following changes and now I get this…: ```django.db.utils.OperationalError: table user_profile_product has no column named product_user_id```

Comment: product = Product(product_name=name, product_description=description, product_price =price, product_user=user)

Comment: Yes, I did it like that and I got the same error.